# GNU Screen running a bash init script

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I'm sure there is an answer to this in the manual to screen, but I can't find it!
I want the bash shell spawned by GNU screen to source in a file in addition to the .bashrc that it already runs.

I can't put a call to the file in .bashrc because on our site .bashrc files get regenerated automatically on login.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I created this little script (screen_bash.sh):

```
bash --rcfile ~/.screen_bashrc
```

Then added

```
shell $HOME/screen_bash.sh
```

To my .screenrc

The ~/.screen_bashrc file was

```
<my_setup_stuff>
export SHELL=bash
```

The SHELL=bash is necessary so that programs like vim can launch sub-shells correctly.

Comment: If the custom init script happens to be `.bash_profile` (as in my case), then the content of `screen_bash.sh` is better as: `bash --login`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want this file to be sourced every single time a new screen window is opened? If so, the [shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Shell) command allows you to overwrite what is run when you create a new screen window (by default it's just $SHELL). You can set this to be a script of your choice that at the end runs your shell.

Comment: Thanks - this and the other answer sorted me out.

Comment: can you post the answer. I have the same question and I am still not sure how to invoke my ~/.bash_profile from .screenrc

Answer (score 2):

```
screen bash --rcfile yourfile.rc
```

`yourfile.rc` should source `.bashrc`.

**EDIT**: This doesn't really do what you want, I just realised you probably want it to apply to *all* shells started by screen.

Comment: Thanks - I put your suggestion in my .screenrc using the shell command (as described above) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had been doing it before, but now I realised that it's better to run as a system init service. You can find my script attached to [this bug report](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381451). Hopefully it will be available as part of screen ebuild in Gentoo. I'll keep it up to date on [github](https://gist.github.com/1186575).

```
start() {

for SCREENRC in /etc/screen.d/* ; do 

    SESSION="$(basename $SCREENRC)"

    ## I don't think there may be a security issue,
    ## provided that users will not be have write
    ## permission in /etc/screen.d/ and if anyone
    ## gained access to mod the session file, they
    ## are in already anyhow!
    BELONGS="$(stat $SCREENRC --printf=%U)"

    MYSHELL="$(getent passwd $BELONGS | cut -d: -f7)"


    COMMAND="/usr/bin/screen -- -U -D -m -c ${SCREENRC} -S ${SESSION} -t ${SESSION}"

    ## Why on earth would one write this ???
    #HOMEDIR="$(getent passwd $BELONGS | cut -d: -f6)"

    ebegin "Starting screen session ${SESSION} for ${BELONGS}"

    PIDFILE="/var/run/screen.${BELONGS}.${SESSION}.pid"

    start-stop-daemon \
        --env TERM="rxvt" \
        --env HOME="~${BELONGS}" \
        --env SCREEN_SESSION=${SESSION} \
        --user $BELONGS \
        --chdir "~${BELONGS}" \
        --make-pidfile \
        --background \
        --pidfile=${PIDFILE} \
        --exec ${COMMAND}
    eend $?
done

}




stop() {

## Perhaps we should determin this by pidfiles ...
## but this way is not bad either!
for SCREENRC in /etc/screen.d/* ; do 

    SESSION="$(basename $SCREENRC)"
    BELONGS="$(stat $SCREENRC --printf=%U)"

    PIDFILE="/var/run/screen.${BELONGS}.${SESSION}.pid"
    PROCESS="$(cat ${PIDFILE})"

    if [ -e /proc/${PROCESS}/status ]; then

    grep -i "Name:" /proc/${PROCESS}/status | grep -iq "screen" || continue

    ebegin "Stopping screen session ${SESSION} for ${BELONGS} (PID: ${PROCESS})"

    ## There other things we can try here ...
    ## perhaps add /etc/screen.d/$SESSION.stop

    ## It will CERTAINly kill the righ screen!
    CERTAIN="${PROCESS}.${SESSION}"
    env TERM="urxvt" \
        start-stop-daemon \
            --user ${BELONGS} \
            --exec /usr/bin/screen -- -S $CERTAIN -X quit
    eend $?

    fi

    rm -f $PIDFILE

done
}
```