# How to immediately execute a command after creating a Screen?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

**Problem :** 
After i create a screen :

*SCREENDIR=/home/scigirl/.screendir screen -S screenName*

I want to execute the command below automatically :

*source private/ProjetoMestrado/virtualenv-15.0.3/myVE/bin/activate*

--
Is this possible? If so , how?
Editing bashrc wont affect the screen on creation event, so.. Any way to do it?

**Reference**

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `/etc/screenrc` and `~/.screenrc` (for user settings)

You could be also interested with:
[GNU Screen running a bash init script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985585/gnu-screen-running-a-bash-init-script)

Comment: It worked, however i had to add a .screenrc file on $HOME and uncomment : # make the shell in every window a login shell
shell -$SHELL and add $shell $HOME/.bash_profile in the end.